# ASP.Net MVC Get QueryString Value using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web Application. I have a Razor View which enables the User to Create a new entry in the database. Within this Create View, there is a Drop Down List and when the User selects an option the following JQuery code fires

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#gradeID").change(ChangeEventOfDDL);

function ChangeEventOfDDL() {
    var dropDownValue = $('#gradeID').val();
    //alert(dropDownValue);
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: '/FormEmployment/CreateSpecialtiesPartialView/' + dropDownValue,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#SpecialtiesContent').html(data);
        }
    });
}

});
```

As you can see within this code I retrieve the selected Drop Down List value using

```
var dropDownValue = $('#gradeID').val();
```

When a User is Editing an entry, I wish to fire off a similar piece of code, only this time I would like to retrieve the entry ID in the QueryString which will look something like this

```
http://localhost:56354/FormEmployment/Edit/41
```

Does anyone know how I can get the value 41 using JQuery or is this even possible?

Thanks for your help.

Tony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make an assumption that the value you want to get is always after the last slash in the url, you can try:

```
location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

By using location.pathname, you don't have to worry about query string parameters, so the url could be `http://localhost:56354/FormEmployment/Edit/41?foo=bar` and it will still work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The value that you're after in your example is actually part of the path, not part of a querystring.

If you do actually want to get a value from the querystring, you can do something like this:

```
getParameterByName: function (name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```